# Loop for imacros/JS not working opinions/suggests are welcome

Tags: javascript, imacros

So I have a simple script that works flawlessly the first run though but then gets a false positive every other time it is looped.  Firstly, the script reads a data source (.csv) file and pulls a single keyword from it at a time and looks for said keyword anywhere on the current tab, if it locates it, it carries on and does the commands as planed. If the keyword is not found, it refers to the datasource and retrieves the next keyword and starts reading the page all over again, rinse and repeat 128 times, again if any of the keywords are found to carry on with the task. If none of the 128 keywords are found it is to close the tab with no work completed.

The above script works great. The problem is when I put the entire thing in a do-while loop (I've set it to continue looping until all tabs are closed and the script basically just kills itself, which is fine) the problem is I get a false positive after the last (128) check. I added alerts to output both the keyword, and the counter(i), and cycled through the whole script to ensure it's pulling the proper keyword at the proper loop. I have no clue why it's assuming it found a match AFTER the 128 checks have completed and only AFTER the first over-all run though was successful.

Code below:

```
   do {
    var datasource, macro, retcode, numberOfLinesInDatasource, aTagWasFound, keyword; 

    datasource = "S:\\Stuff.csv"  
    numberOfLinesInDatasource = 128;
    aTagWasFound = false;


// loop through all lines in datasource
for (var i = 1; i < numberOfLinesInDatasource+1; i++)
{

  // get the datasource value at this line
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "SET !DATASOURCE " + datasource + "\n";
    macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1\n";
    macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + i + "\n";
    macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);
    keyword = iimGetLastExtract();
    // search for this keyword
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 1\n"; 
    macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\n";             
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=TXT:*" + keyword + "*\n";
    // alert(keyword)
    // alert(i)
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);

    // if retcode is 1 then the tag was found move on to next step else break and
    if (retcode === 1){
        // move on to next step
        aTagWasFound = true;
        //alert(keyword);
        break;
    }
    // tag not found try the next value
}

if (!aTagWasFound)
{
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "TAB CLOSE\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);
} else 
{
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Open\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Take\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Relationships\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:ModifyLinks.html ATTR=NAME:******-RefersTo CONTENT=stuff\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:ModifyLinks.html ATTR=*\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Resolve\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:TicketUpdate ATTR=NAME:UpdateContent CONTENT=stuff\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:TicketUpdate ATTR=NAME:UpdateSubject CONTENT=stuff\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:TicketUpdate ATTR=NAME:UpdateType CONTENT=%private\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:TicketUpdate ATTR=*\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Display\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=TXT:RT/texas.net:<SP>Ticket* EXTRACT=TXT\n";
    macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=\"S:\\Stuff\" FILE=Exports.csv\n";
    macro += "TAB CLOSE\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);    
}

}while(1)
```

so again, the script will work perfectly on the first page, but after it closes a tab and starts the whole loop over again on a new tab it will read all 128 keywords properly, this time NOT finding a match but it runs the commands as if it did anyways.

Any hints/suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in using tabs. So (1) read carefully [wiki about TAB](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAB). (2) In your code you do not define them explicitly – such an approach is not good. (3) To run the script from the last tab is better, I think.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. but the whole point of closing the tab it that the script always runs on tab 1. constantly closing the tab and making the past tense tab 2 to now be tab 1 before it loops all over again. i'll also look and see if just moving over a tab without closing any tabs may be an option as well. I'll play with it, thanks for the idea